# (Ubuntu touch) touch-screen calibration

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screen, touchscreen

after replacing my aquaris E.5's touch screen (A tiny scratch broke the touch effect), I simply can't use it because the touch screen is not calibrated ...

Unfortunately, when I look for it, I only find How to calibrate external touch screens.

I saw that we can do that in android with an application. Should I install android and calibrate my phone with it, and then reinstall ubuntu ?
Can I do it directly with adb ?

If there are any other methods you might know, I'm deeply interested !

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: I might add that I can have the log-event from /dev/input/event4 (with adb). And if I find out how to send a pattern of points on the screen, I'll be able to calculate the transformation matrix (rotation, translation, scale). But I have no idea where to put these data in order to make mir performing the transformation ! any idea ? :3